# How to insert date in Oracle 10g xe?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I  did the following:

1. ```
     CREATE TABLE BOOK(
             BOOK_ID VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
             ISBN_10 VARCHAR(10),
             TITLE VARCHAR(50),
             CATEGORY VARCHAR(25),
             PRICE DECIMAL(6,2),
             BINDING VARCHAR(2),
             PUB_DATE DATE,
             AUTHOR_ID SMALLINT,
             PUBLISHER_ID SMALLINT
             );
   ```

2.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

3.

```
INSERT INTO  BOOK
VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO SmallTalk','IT',157.00,'S',**'26-01-1991'**,13,103);
```

It gave an **error**:
 **ORA-01843: not a valid month**

However if do the **following** there is **no problem:**

Query:

```
INSERT INTO 
BOOK
VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO Small Talk','IT',157.00,'S','**26-JAN-1991**',13,103);
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 6):

You want to read the [Datetime Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) section of the manual. Alternatives are:

- Use a date literal: `DATE '1991-01-26'`
- Convert from string: `TO_DATE('26-01-1991', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

If you set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` you can omit `TO_DATE()`'s second argument but not skip the function entirely.

See also: [Datetime Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me.  That implies that your alter statement did not work for some reason. However, it is not good practice to assume a specific date format on a system when using literals.  Instead, cast the literal with a format mask on the insert, such as:

```
INSERT INTO BOOK
VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO Small Talk','IT',157.00,'S',
       to_date('26-JAN-1991','DD-MON-YYYY'), 13,103);
```

(or whatever format you require as a literal input value)

Comment: The default NLS date format for Oracle is 'DD-MON-YYYY', but as @OldProgrammer advises, it is better to be on the cautious side and cast the date string using your chosen date-mask.  Trusting implicit data value conversions such as a string-to-date operation may lead to problems if migrating code or sharing source with other systems that have different date format defaults.

Answer (score 1):

This because in your database, nls_date_time is set to 'DD-MON-RRRR' format, you can check this using
`select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS`

In this query

`INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO SmallTalk','IT',157.00,'S','26-01-1991',13,103);`

date format is 'dd-mm-rrrr', change the statement as

`INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO SmallTalk','IT',157.00,'S',to_date('26-01-1991', 'dd-mm-rrrr'),13,103);`

and it will also run since you have now provided the date format.

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

then your insert must match this format, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES('4','123459','INTRODUCTION TO SmallTalk','IT',157.00,'S',
'26-01-1991 00:00:00'
,13,103);
```

However, the more secure way is to use date literals or TO_DATE function.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('07-JAN-96');
```

Oracle always takes `"DD-MMM-YY"` format. You should write your month as the first 3 characters of month name.

Comment: @Tunaki could you explain if this answer is valid